# Is there an easy way to flip a matrix (horizontal or vertical)?

Tags: r, matrix

In Matlab, I know there are some functions that can flip matrix, say flip left and right (horizontal) or up and down (vertical), but I have no idea if there are similar ones in R.

For example, assuming we have a matrix `m <- matrix(1:12,nrow = 3)`, we want

- Horizontal flip to get `mh`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10    7    4    1
[2,]   11    8    5    2
[3,]   12    9    6    3
```

- Vertical flip to get `mv`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    6    9   12
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    1    4    7   10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `pracma` package could help you

```
mh <- pracma::fliplr(m)
```

and

```
mv <- pracma::flipud(m)
```

such that

```
> mh
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   10    7    4    1
[2,]   11    8    5    2
[3,]   12    9    6    3

> mv
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    6    9   12
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    1    4    7   10
```

Comment: Wow, the same function names with MATLAB!!!

Answer (score 2):

We can do the sequence reversed as index for column, row to get the flipped datasets

```
m[, ncol(m):1]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   10    7    4    1
#[2,]   11    8    5    2
#[3,]   12    9    6    3

m[nrow(m):1, ]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    6    9   12
#[2,]    2    5    8   11
#[3,]    1    4    7   10
```